# Reputation from sister sites should be considered

Tags: discussion, tags, migration, reputation

Sometimes I would like to edit the tags on a question, but I don't have the 'reputation' to do so.  How about taking into account reputation on sister sites?  I have over 100K total between stackoverflow and dba.stackexchange, so I understand tagging and make good use of adding/deleting tags on those sites.  But I can't do it here.

And ditto for some other actions.  In particular, I would like to push about half the [mysql] questions on ServerFault to the above-mentioned sites, where they are likely to get more attention.

Answer (score 2):

For such suggestion I think it must be asked on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), but please validate if it was already asked in the past there. I would not migrate directly as often duplicate get downvoted a lot on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

I think the rational of MSE is you can be a good programmer, but a total outsider to be a sysadmin, thus the right gain are by site.

A good exemple; I'am French native and my reputation here is good, but giving me the editing right on like [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) would not be ok, as I'am far to be the best in English.

In your case it's borderline as tag like mysql are shared between DBA and here, and often a DBA question could fit both site (but on StackOverflow the tag would possibly mean more the API side of the product) So maybe there is a case to do on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) when a site share some tags on sisters site like you state, but I will leave you the choice to post the feature-request on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) or not.